# Is Wolverine an organ donor?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I was curious about the nature of Wolverine's healing abilities and some of its oddities.  I've heard that Angel can provide limited healing via blood donation.

- Are there any canon examples of Wolverine donating an organ or blood?
- If so, does this organ exhibit any additional healing or resiliency?
- If not, his blood is D+.  Is that why he can't or doesn't?

I would prefer to avoid *X-Men Origins* and any land wars with Asia.

Comment: Thes seems like it could be a duplicate but I didn't find it.  If I'll happily delete.

Comment: Speculation: mutant blood may have adverse effects for non-mutants, and would likely be unwanted by discriminatory blood banks anyway for social reasons (like the ban on gay men donating blood in the real world).

Comment: @Nerrolken Potentially but he is in emergency situations frequently (where they may be no one else with... D+... blood) and there are non-mutants.  It is probable that, in general, mutants would be discriminated in this way (aka I agree).

Comment: @Nerrolken the ban was due to increased risk of std/hiv from gay men, however, they are currently lifting that ban to due better testing procedures, not for social reasons. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28118/is-the-us-fda-policy-of-deferring-blood-donations-from-msm-justified-by-increase

Comment: @Himarm Like I said, there are probably similar medical concerns about mutant blood.  But there is also a clear social aspect to denying blood from any gay man, even though not all gay men have HIV and plenty of straight people do (fear-based generalizations, at least, even if you don't think there's actual discrimination).  Similarly, I think there would be a stigma against accepting mutant blood, because of discrimination, as well as dumb superstitions and social panic about it turning you into a mutant yourself, causing mutant children, etc.

Comment: @Nerrolken yes i fully agree there is discrimination it would most likely apply in the sense towards mutants(as it does towards the gay community), but i like to share any insights i have about perceived "truths" of discrimination and the actual facts behind said measures. And this was a fairly recent question on skeptics so it immediately came to mind.

Comment: I'd love to have his liver. Then I could drink non-stop too.

Comment: another Canadian, Deadpool, donates organs to FauX-Men in the 2012 Deadpool comic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no evidence that I am aware of of Logan acting as an organ donor, but he *is* a blood donor.

Specifically, his blood was provided to Jubilee after she became a vampire. The healing factor in his blood at the time allowed Jubilee some regenerative powers, helped with some personality issues, and even allowed her to withstand some sunlight.

The transfusions seem to begin in [Wolverine & Jubilee #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_and_Jubilee_Vol_1_1).

> Dr Rao: But as long as Jubilee continues to be transfused with Logan's blood, it'll keep the edge off her id.

[image: I want to transfuse your blood]

Comment: In which comic/serial?

Comment: That...certainly is donating blood!  I don't suppose you know whether the power mimicry is her vampiric ability or solely his ability?  Aka is it "you are what you eat" or "cells heal what they are in"?

Comment: @richard It all started after the *Curse of the Mutants* storyline, but I forget exactly which issue I read about the transfusions. I'll dig further tonight, but I feel like it was in the recent "Wolverine & Jubilee" run.

Comment: @kaine It was left a bit unclear, as I recall, but I believe Jubilee was getting blood transfusions, not drinking it.